# Член Клуба - прописная или маленькая буквы?

Tags: грамматика, прописная-строчная

Добрый день!

В нашей компании принято во всех текстах писать "Член Клуба" (оба слова с заглавной буквы). Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли это и как можно это объяснить с точки зрения правил русского языка? Спасибо!

Comment: @olya13, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если это в формальном тексте от имени клуба, то упоминание Клуба с заглавной буквы логично: оно однозначно указывает именно на этот клуб. Что касается выражения "член Клуба", то написание первого слова с большой буквы оправдано лишь при оговоренной условности статуса члена клуба. Например, в начале документа даётся строгое определение тому, кто признаётся членом клуба, с указанием требований к такому человеку (наличие удостоверения, регулярная уплата взносов и т.п.), а далее при слылке на официальный статус Члена Клуба растолковываются права исключительно таких *полноправных* его членов. В менее формальных документах или текстах о клубе, написанных вне клуба, естественнее писать "член клуба". Но если в названии клуба фигурирует слово "Клуб" (особенно, в его начале), то написание этого слова с заглавной буквы можно трактовать как сокращение его наименования.

Comment: Александр, если слово клуб входит в название клуба, то да, писать клуб с большой буквы естественно. А в иных случаях писать клуб с большой буквы на том основании,чтобы указать, что кто-то является полноправным членом данного конкретного клуба, а не другого клуба - не логично. Почему вы считаете,что если в названии клуба фигурирует само слово "клуб", то оно является сокращением?

Comment: "Член клуба" или "Член Клуба" - условные обозначения, которые можно принять в рамках одного документа и ссылаться на них исключительно в нём, подобно тому, как в документах пишут напр. "далее именуемый Заказчиком". Согласен, что в формулировке статуса члена клуба нет прямой необходимости оба слова писать с большой буквы, но логику в этом можно усмотреть, если во всём документе "Клуб" составители пишут с большой буквы (для устранения путаницы, напр. с членством в "клубах"-филиалах с независимыми финансами и т.п.) За пределами клуба вне связи с названием - с маленькой.

Comment: @Alex_ander, вот именно -- внутри официального документа (скажем, устава). А во всех текстах (как сказано в вопросе) решительно не вижу необходимости. Неоправданная калька с английского, я думаю.

Answer (score 1):

Если словосочетании "Член клуба" используется в своем прямом значении, то никаких оснований писать с прописной буквы нет.